# Ruby on Rails: Braintree::AuthenticationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

Hello there I have a problem with my Braintree implementation! I created a Sandbox account on braintree websites and then added the gem to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'braintree', "~> 2.62.0"
```

Create the file /initializers/braintree.rb:

```
  Braintree::Configuration.environment = :sandbox
  Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id = ENV['MERCHANT_ID']
  Braintree::Configuration.public_key = ENV['PUBLIC_KEY_B']
  Braintree::Configuration.private_key = ENV['PRIVATE_KEY_B']
```

(I use Figaro Gem to handle constant: application.yml

```
MERCHANT_ID             : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
PUBLIC_KEY_B            : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
PRIVATE_KEY_B           : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

)

Added this route following the documentation in the Routes file:

```
  scope '/api' do
    scope  '/v1' do
      scope '/client_token' do
        get '/' => Braintree::ClientToken.generate
      end
      ...
    end
  end
```

Now if I start the server via the command rails s I get the following error:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
I, [2016-06-28T11:59:59.271177 #16383]  INFO -- : [Braintree] [28/Jun/2016 09:59:59 UTC] POST /merchants/xxxxxxxxxxx/client_token 401
Exiting
/Users/xxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/braintree-2.62.0/lib/braintree/util.rb:51:in `raise_exception_for_status_code': Braintree::AuthenticationError (Braintree::AuthenticationError)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Your API credentials might be incorrect - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/exceptions/ruby

Comment: I agree with @NnN, please [replace with your credentials](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials) and try it.

Comment: You were right! Just a character more in the credentials :)